# How to execute a sql query in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I want to execute a query like the following query in zf2.

> SHOW COLUMNS FROM Mytable LIKE 'Mycolumn'

What is the correct way of doing so?

By the way i am using `AbstractTableGateway` class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do it like this:

1. [Create an adapter](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html)
2. Pass it to the chosen class and run something like this:

   ```
   $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Mytable LIKE 'Mycolumn'"; 

   $statement = $this->adapter->query($sql); 
   return $statement->execute();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I know reply on a very old thread, but maybe some one looking for SELECT with LIKE

```
 $this->table = $data['table'];
    $select = new Select();
    $spec = function (Where $where) {
        $where->like('company', '%1%');
    };
    $select->from($this->table);
    $select->where($spec);
    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
    $resultSet->buffer();
    return $resultSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Some thing found From Google,Hope This helps u...

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select(); // @return Zend\Db\Sql\Select
$insert = $sql->insert(); // @return Zend\Db\Sql\Insert
$update = $sql->update(); // @return Zend\Db\Sql\Update
$delete = $sql->delete(); // @return Zend\Db\Sql\Delete
```

For More Info Visit : [click](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)

Comment: No, they just work for DML statements. but my query is different. it is a `show columns` statement.